# p-values for Kendall's Tau-b in Kendall R package

Tags: r, p-value

I am using Kendall's Tau b to measure the strength of relationship between x and y, using the Kendall R package. x has many ties, y has a few (see image attached).

If I correlate x with y, then correlate -x with y the tau values are identical, but the p values are not. x is an ordinal landscape health measure. I arbitarily assign higher values to x where health is better, but there is no absolute reason to do this one way or the other. Consequently it seems the p values are subject to the direction values are ranked, which seems inappropriate.

So my question is whether the p values are being calculated correctly and/or whether I am using it incorrectly to get this kind of result?

raw data and Kendall() results
[image]

Comment: I really would not worry about the difference between 1e-7 and 8e-8

Comment: Thanks Richard. I take you point. Might just be a good case for letting go of my inner sock-sorter :) Cheers